# Python Flask - What is the best way to conditionally display WTF fields based on prior responses?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a WTF form with several fields where I only want to display certain fields based on the responses to previous fields without refreshing the page.  For example, say I have a field:

```
URLInd = BooleanField(u'Do you have a website?',validators=[DataRequired())
```

Which if checked, I want to display:

```
URL = TextField(u'Please enter your web address',validators=[DataRequired(), URL()])
```

So "URLInd" can be shown at the initial page load, but I only want "URL" shown if URLInd == True.

HTML:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form"  enctype=multipart/form-data action>
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens="only") }}
  {{ wtf.form_field(form.URLInd) }}
  {{ wtf.form_field(form.URL) }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Based on my research, I suspect I need to use Javascript and AJAX, but I have no experience using either and I haven't been able to apply any of the examples I've found to this problem.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use Javascript. One option would be to load the secondary field hidden, and then display it conditionally based on the first field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field have arg `message` for replace default error message in defaults validators. For replace use kwargs `message="u error message for view invalid this field"`

Simple example

```
URLInd = BooleanField(u'Do you have a website?',validators=[URL(message="I want MY MESSAGE ERROR THIS FIELD")])
```